# .htaccess displaying incorrect url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

When I navigate to the page:

myexample.com/independent

I expected it to bring me to my independent page. All other pages are working correctly. This one does not however and the URL is displayed as:

myexample.com/independent/?pageid=independent

the rewrite rule I am using is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ page.php?pageid=$1

ErrorDocument 404 myexample/404page
```

Can you see anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is `independent` a sub-directory?

Comment: yes it is and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@anubhava answered it correctly, the issue was that the independent was also a subdirectory.